# How to close popup window by button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to close popup window by button, but I don't have any idea.
When I used Java Swing, I remember the function was automatic...

So.. What should I do?

And I also want to make more space between button and text. If you have any idea, please help me.

```
                    Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                    dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {


                            }
                        }
                    });

                    VBox vbox = new VBox(new Text("Wrong ID & PW!!"), new Button("Ok."));
                    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(15));

                    dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
                    dialogStage.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `dialogStage.close()`

```
 button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                            dialogStage.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Also you are adding a `new Button("Ok.")` to the `VBox` which is wrong, add the `button` which you created before

As for the space between the button and text, this should work

```
 VBox.setMargin(text, new Insets(20));
 VBox.setMargin(button, new Insets(20));
```

Comment: but I think I have to set controller,, It doesn't work TT

Comment: The problem is with your `button` you are creating the button and adding a listener but you are adding a new button to the `VBox`

Comment: In the question's code sample it never uses the button named `button`. Instead of `Button button = new Button();`, write `Button button = new Button("OK");`. Instead of `new Button("Ok.")` in the VBox constructor, just reference `button`.  Use `button.setDefault(true)` instead of registering a key press handler for the button.  Use `button.setOnAction` to trigger the close event handler.  Consider using an [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) instead of creating your own dialog.

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you too ;)